# Replace section of an xml file with awk or sed

Tags: xml, regex, bash, sed, awk

I'd like to replace the section below between `<restApi>` and `</restApi>` (including restApi tags) with another string:

```
...
  <restApi>
    <baseUrl>https://domain.com/nexus</baseUrl>
    <forceBaseUrl>true</forceBaseUrl>
    <uiTimeout>60000</uiTimeout>
  </restApi>
...
```

Using awk, I use the following command to do the replacement :

```
awk '/<restApi>/,/<\/restApi>/ {sub(/.*/,"<sometag>stuff</sometag>")}1' file.xml
```

The problem is that awk replaces each line with the replacement string so I'm getting this output:

```
...
<sometag>stuff</sometag>
<sometag>stuff</sometag>
<sometag>stuff</sometag>
<sometag>stuff</sometag>
<sometag>stuff</sometag>
...
```

- What am I missing in the awk command to have only one `"<sometag>stuff</sometag>"` in the result?
- How do I do it with sed instead?
- Spacing/tabs get lost during replacement. How can I preserve it?

Comment: `.*` this means all characters on the line, so every line is change.  What is expected output?

Comment: Error number one: XML is not a string. You are not supposed to do string processing on XML. Use an XML-aware tool like xsltproc.

Comment: @Jotne 
expected output is 
...
<sometag>stuff</sometag>
...

Comment: @Tomalak  for simple task you can use `awk` `sed` and other stuff to do what you like, but is it better to use another tool for larger handling of xml files, yes

Comment: @PapelPincel Replace what, with what?  I do see you like some new, but not what to be replaced.

Comment: @Jotne No. Because if you start that way it's very likely that feature creep will kick in and the script will gradually be "refined" - until you are at a point where you do something totally inappropriate to the XML with awk because you don't have the time to rewrite it all in a proper tool. (Plus, it is generally always wrong to use regular expressions on XML and there simply never is a sufficient justification.)

Comment: Plus, it is generally always wrong to use XML. Just for the record :-)

Comment: @SzG it's a Nexus OSS config file :-)

Comment: Yes. Using XML is wrong but necessary :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single line **pure awk** solution that solves your problem

```
awk  'BEGIN {A = 1};/<restApi>/{A=0; print "<sometag>stuff</sometag>"};/.*/ { if ( A == 1) print $0};/<\/restApi>/{A=1}; ' file.xml
```

If you're dealing often with xml transforms you should consider using xslt, as others say

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in my comment above, use an XML aware tool.

XSLT is one, so here is a simple stylesheet that replaces `<restApi>` elements while leaving everything else alone, including spaces and tabs.

```
<!-- newRestApi.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="restApi">
    <sometag>stuff</sometag>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Use with `xsltproc` is dead-simple:

```
xsltproc newRestApi.xsl input.xml > output.html
```

Answer (score 4):

It's an incorrect approach to parse `xml` with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) or [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). You should use a language with a parser. Here I will provide an example with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and its `XML::Twig` module:

Assuming following input file:

```
<root>
  <restApi>
    <baseUrl>https://domain.com/nexus</baseUrl>
    <forceBaseUrl>true</forceBaseUrl>
    <uiTimeout>60000</uiTimeout>
  </restApi>
  <t>data</t>
  <restApi>
    <baseUrl>https://domain.com/nexus</baseUrl>
    <forceBaseUrl>true</forceBaseUrl>
    <uiTimeout>60000</uiTimeout>
  </restApi>
</root>
```

And following `perl` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'restApi' => sub { 
            my $elem = XML::Twig::Elt->new('sometag', 'stuff');
            $elem->replace($_);
        },
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
)->parsefile(shift)->print;
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl xmlfile
```

That yields:

```
<root>
  <sometag>stuff</sometag>
  <t>data</t>
  <sometag>stuff</sometag>
</root>
```

Comment: +1 for sane approach plus the proof that doing the right thing it isn't difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you pipe your awk output into `uniq`, you probably get what you want.